# Selection in editable element incorrect if click within selection

Tags: javascript, click, selection, designmode

I just noticed a faulty behaviour within a editable element (design mode) affecting the selection.

Here is the example:

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  // get selection
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount === 1) {
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    console.log(range.startOffset);
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#el {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="el" contenteditable="true">
  Select whole Text<br/>
  Then click within selection
</div>
```

This example outputs the start offset of the selection every time a mouse click occurs within the element. This usually works fine, but not in the following case:

1. Select a range of text (start offset is printed correctly)
2. Click **within** the selected text (start offset is printed incorrectly, start offset of former selection is printed)
3. Click **again** on the same position (start offset is now printed correctly)

So every time when the selection is set within the former selection the position cannot be retrieved correctly.

The error seems to occur in every browser (tested in FF, IE, Chrome).

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this?